# TOTALYTD returning values equal to sliced values even when filtered by all dates

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I have the following columns in my data table:

```
[Date],[Week_Num],[Month_Num],[Month_Word],[Year],[Username],[Transactions],[Gross],[Turnover]
```

I have my pivot set up like this:

```
report filer: [Year]=2016
vertical slicer: [week_Num]

[Username],[Turnover],[Gross],[YTD_Turnover]
```

Turnover and gross columns show sliced values indicated by which week number is selected in the slicer. The problem is the [YTD_Turnover] column is showing the same values as sliced. I'm currently using this formula:

```
=TOTALYTD(SUM(data[Turnover]),data[Date])
```

I tried using this formula but it's not returning any values:

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(data[Turnover]),data[Year]=2016,ALL(data[Week]))
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here since when I check the formula, it say's there's no errors found.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filters in TOTALYTD. Try:

```
=TOTALYTD(SUM(data[Turnover]),data[Date],ALL(data))
```

Comment: I tried the formula but when I change the week number in the slicer it will also change the value on that measure. I was hoping to get this number to be static and to strictly display YTD values.

Comment: @Jeho, I see. In this case I find it somewhat surprising your second formula does not work. In your second formula you say `data[Week]` and on the slicer you say `[week_Num]`. Can you confirm there is no mistake here? Also I suppose you have a date column, can you please try `year(data[date]) = 2016` instead of what you have now in the second formula?

Comment: I tried this formula and found it better since it's more versatile as I can use it for MTD and lifetime values. 

=CALCULATE(SUM(data[Financial Gross]),YEAR(data[Settled Date])=2016,ALL(data[Week]))

I'm not really sure if it the TOTALYTD has and significant effect on calculation speed compared to CALCULATE since my table is only 150k line.